# How to render two different view models in the same action with Zend\Cache\Pattern\CaptureCache

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework2

With any regular page I set up a `Zend\Cache\Pattern\CaptureCache`, catch the `onFinish` event, and send the rendered version to a message queue for later processing. So far, so good...

Problem: sometimes I need to render **two** versions of the same action in the same request; one for mobile and one for desktop and I'm not sure how to do that.

If it helps, the actions that I need to "double render" actually create two discrete ViewModel objects so that I can have full control over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a service that given these two view models would figure out which one is mobile and which one is desktop. Then it would grab the layout and render each view model separately. Finally it would bypass any caching and generate both files manually.

Answer (score -1):

With the setTemplate method :)

First you create your phtml view file (already done I suppose).

then you declare it in your view manager config / template_map :

In the Module.config.php file (you create the alias to call it later in your controller) :

```
return array(
    //[...],
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map' => array(
            // [...],
            'index/test'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/mymodule/index/test.phtml',
        ),
       //here your template_path_stack as usual
    ),
    // [...],
);
```

(of course, put your own path ;) )

Then in your controller :

```
public function indexAction(){
    $view = new ViewModel();
    if (/*here your tests*/) {
        $view->setTemplate('index/test'); //here the name declared in the template_map
    }
    return $view;
}
```

you can learn a lot here about views (and layouts): http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but... did you even read my question? I know how to change the template on a view or a layout; that's not the issue. Your answer does not even mention CaptureCache which is right in the title of the question.